# hook_civicrm_postSave_table_name not called on table update

Tags: civievent, database, hooks

In Drupal, I'm using [hook_civicrm_postSave_table_name](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/hooks/hook_civicrm_postSave_table_name/) to listen for CiviEvent registrations.  I've implemented hook_civicrm_postSave_civicrm_participant($dao) where I test for certain status_id values and do something with a custom Drupal module.  Although this works for non-paid events, I noticed that it's not working for paid events.

The reason is because during the payment process the status_id is '6', but when the payment is processed and the status_id changes to '1', the hook isn't called (The hook does get called when the database row is written with status_id 6).

The documentation says "This hook will get called again with every update", but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this a bug, or should I be getting the participant status update in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_civicrm_post hook which gets called every time a core object is written to db. Detailed description can be found here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_post/